# Unable to press the "X" or close bottom on the top right of the window application

Tags: window, sdl

I am experimenting SDL Events and I came into a problem. For some reason, I am unable to press the "X" or close bottom on the top right of the window application. Now I am currently unsure if that is related to the SDL coding, or it's a problem of window browser.

Does anyone know if it's either a SDL problem or a Window problem?

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like you're not handling the SDL_QUIT event.  After you've polled the SDL event queue, you'll want to handle the SDL_QUIT event as well as other keyboard input and such.